# Why are .weights files the same size when learning YOLO?

Tags: deep-learning, yolo

I made a YOLO model to learn about cars and learned it from Google Colaboratory. I then added more datasets and created new datasets and trained new versions to increase accuracy. The new dataset had about seven times more data than the previous version. (70k)
But why does it take the same time to learn the previous version?
Also, the size of the Weights file is the same, but I don't know why.

1. Why is the learning time of 10k data the same as the learning time of 70k data?
2. Why is the size of the weight file the same as 10k data and 70k data?

Comment: Which version YOLO are you using?

Comment: The number of weights is independent of the dataset size, there is no reason why the weights file would have a different size.

Comment: @JuanCamiloRiveraPalacio  v4? or tiny?

Answer (score 0):

1. Learning time will be same for all datasets. Because when training you didn't change cfg file. if you will change will be differet. you can change steps and you can see.
2. Weights also will be same for all dataset for all yolov3 models. Because you are using yolov3 weights. For example, if you will use yolov3-tiny for training,  will be different from yolov3 model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).